# MDPI to HDPI SystemUI.apk porting

Tags: android, hdpi, mdpi

I'm trying to port an MDPI SystemUI.apk to HDPI. I've decompiled the file, added the line -

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml, and also I've made drawable-hdpi folder with required images, but still it is loading resources from drawable-mdpi. Any ways to fix this?

By the way, the Android version is 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Well android adjust its screen density according to device it working on, If you have both folders HDPI and MDPI available, it will take near best suitable resources for your application. Please check whether device is HDPI or not.

Also add following to supports-screen tag.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" >
</supports-screens>
```

Comment: Tried it already, but it is just refusing to use the drawable-hdpi folder!

Answer (score 0):

Android won't load HDPI resources if the system is not configured to be HDPI.

The system determines its density based on the configured display dpi value and will then try to load appropriate resources. There is a system property `ro.sf.lcd_density` for that. If you set that value to 240 the device will consider itself HDPI. (120 = low, 160 = med, 320 = xhigh)

http://wccftech.com/article/increase-screen-dpi/ should tell you how you can change that value

Comment: My phone is a HDPI phone, and that value is already present on my phone's build.prop. I'm trying to use a MDPI phone's SystemUI.apk, but it is just ignoring hdpi resources.